# calendar serialization deserialization

Tags: java, datetime

When I serialize date on one pc1 and deserialize it on another pc2 I get local date of pc2.
What will I get when do the same with Calendar instance? Will situation will be same or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Date` represents a point in time (number of milliseconds from 1st of January 1970). Do not be confused by the time zone in `Date.toString()`, you are always serializing `long` value wrapped in a class.

`Calendar` on the other hand represents date and time *in given time zone*. This means that if the source computer is in GMT+1 and the target one in the GMT+2, but you are sending `Calendar` set to GMT-6, it will be GMT-6 all the way on both sides.

That being said it is much safer (and uses less bandwidth) to send `Date` and let every computer *display* it using local time zone.

Answer (score 2):

The Calendar class implements the Serializable, you can use serialization api to save it.
However, I like the timestamp:

> The currently set time for this calendar, expressed in milliseconds
>   after January 1, 1970, 0:00:00 GMT.

We can deserialize timestamp by new Date(timestamp) simply, it will convert to local timezone automatically.

Calendar class also defines the setTime method:

```
Calendar.getInstance().setTime(date)
```

or

```
Calendar.getInstance().setTimeInMillis(ts)
```